# Is the function differentiable at $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given the function $$ f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{\sin(x)^4 \ln(1+x^2)}{(1+\cos(x))^2+y^4},  & \text{if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$} \\
0, & \text{if $(x,y)=(0,0)$}
\end{cases}$$
I want to check if it is differentiable at $(0,0)$.
First I checked if it is continuous at $(0,0)$, I saw it is.
Then I tried using the definition of differentiable function but couldn't get a definite result.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you found the partials are the origin? Do you know how this helps?

Comment: Every function of $x$ and every function of $y$ involved is $C^\infty$ at $0$ and the denominator is non zero in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ hence no computation is needed to see that $f$ is $C^\infty$ at $(0,0)$. More interesting would be the case of $(1-\cos x)^2+y^4$ in the denominator.

Comment: I didnt understand what you meant.

Comment: @YinonEliraz How is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$\frac{\sin(x)^4 \ln(1+x^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \leq \frac{\sin(x)^4 \ln(1+x^2)}{|x|} = \sin(x)^3 \ln(1+x^2)* \frac {\sin(x)}{|x|}$

${(1+\cos(x))^2+y^4}$ is not so intresting because at $(0,0)$ is not $0$